# How can i get back my files from userdata dump (dumepd via LGUP)?

Tags: adb, data-recovery, partitions, lg-v30

A while ago i soft bricked my LG V30, then before i flashed a new Rom i created a LGUP dump which gave me lots of files includung a 54 GB userdata file.
The phone is currently up and running with the new Rom after a factory reset, the thing i am after are my Files that are in the Userdata dump.

What i have tried/googled:

1. I have mounted the system Partition as EXT4 under Ubuntu which has worked perfectly fine, but when i try this with the userdata it doesnt work.
2. I have read that it is possible to (somehow) create a flashable KDZ or TOT file that apparently can be put back on the phone. I had no luck finding a tool or any instructions on how to do this.
3. I have heard that you can push a partition to the Phone via ADB. This went similar to #2 as i wasnt able to find any instructions or something like that on google.
4. Also i have tried to mount the userdata file on my phone through the ADB shell, but this wasnt successful because the shell doesnt have root permissions.
5. I also have tried the partition dl feature in LGUP with the phone in Download mode but UP gives me an error that the file isnt in a KDZ or TOT format.

Can anyone help? I am desperately trying to get my files back.
Does anyone know why the mount under Linux doesnt work? This would be the easyest way to get the files.

Comment: The user data partition is most likely encrypted (Full Disk Encryption) and can only be decrypted using the key integrated into the hardware of your old phone. You can test your user data partition using the Linux command `ent`. For en encrypted file the entropy result should be next to 8 bits per character (7.9... would be a an expected value).

Comment: as Robert stated 1. is impossible. regarding 2./5. please provide file names (backup)